# What is the general solution to this second order nonlinear differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is $$y^3  y'' = 3$$

It would make sense to use the reduction of order method and the substitution w = y' and y'' = w(dw/dy), correct? But I'm not really sure how to proceed once I take the integral $$ \int \frac{dy} {y^3} = \int 3w dw = -2y^{-2} = \frac{3}2 w^2 + C$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have:

$$y''y^{3}=3$$

$$y''=\frac{3}{y^3}$$

Multiply both sides by $y'$, then you have:

$$y'y''=\frac{3y'}{y^3}$$

Note that:

$$y'y''=\left(\frac{(y')^2}{2}\right)'$$

$$\frac{3y'}{y^3}=\frac{3}{2}\left(\frac{-1}{y^2}\right)'$$

So:

$$\frac{(y')^2}{2}=-\frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{y^2}+C$$

$$y'=\sqrt{\frac{-3}{y^2}+C}$$

$$1=\frac{y'}{\sqrt{\frac{-3}{y^2}+C}}$$

$$D=\int_{x_0}^{x}\frac{y'}{\sqrt{\frac{-3}{y^2}+C}}dx=\int_{y(x_0)}^{y(x)}\frac{dt}{\sqrt{\frac{-3}{t^2}+C}}$$